# Logical AND vs Bitwise AND for single bit and multibits

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

What is the functional and physical difference in using Logical AND ( && ) and Bitwise AND (&&) over singlebit and multibit signals.
Below shared cases.

case 1: A[3:0] & B[3:0]  = ?

case 2: A[3:0] && B[3:0] = ?

case 3: A[0:0] & B[3:0] = ?

case 4: A[0:0] && B[3:0] = ?

case 5: &B[3:0] = Bitwise AND of B that shall result in 1 or 0

Comment: Have you done *any* research? This question is about the basics of the basics.

Comment: You marked the both with &&. But one of them is &. Please edit to fix.

Comment: [what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-ampersand-binary-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327680/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-ampersand-binary-opera)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Verilog I’ll assume you want to know that behavior.

Cases 1 and 3, the bitwise AND (single ‘&’) will produce the bit-by-bit AND of the respective bits in each vector. If the vectors are unequal in size, the smaller vector will be zero-extended to the size of the larger vector, producing a result the same size as the larger one.

So case 3 will have A[0:0] expanded to {3’b0, A[0]} prior to ‘&’ with B[3:0].

For any bitwise op, the destination vector should be sized to the largest source vector, otherwise a compiler warning will result. Also note that the source fields will be right-aligned to each other for the ‘&’ operation.

The takeaway: when using bitwise operators, avoid unequally-sized variables, it’s bad coding practice that can result in hard-to-find bugs.

Cases 2 and 4, the logical AND (&&) first tests the bits in each vector for non-zero (does a unary reductive OR), then computes the boolean AND of the two tests. The result is a single bit.

Case 5, the unary reductive AND (&) takes the logical AND of all the bits in a vector. It will also result in a single bit result.

Comment: Just commenting that "will produce the AND of the smaller of the two." seems a very strange phrase for this!  And saying that the "logical and ... applies the logical AND" is a tautology.

Comment: I changed it - refresh.